# C# generate certificate based on template from Active Directory Certificate Services

Tags: c#, service, active-directory, certificate, ca

Using the CA web page https://{CAServerName}/certsrv/certrqma.asp, I can manually create a request based on the template and install the certificate after approval.

How to do the same but in c#?

[image: Example]

Comment: This is far too general a question to get any useful answers.

Comment: There are basically two ways to do this. You can use the SCEP protocol to connect to `https://yourserver/certsrv/mscep.dll` and request a certificate. The server needs to have NDES installed, which is not the same as CA Web Enrollment. Or you can request directly from the CA, perhaps using the relevant Powershell module. Either way, this is too big for a little [so] answer

Answer (score 0):

This is my first time working with certificates and this is what I got.
While searching, I found 2 useful articles:

[How to work with certreq](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/8096a455-1b11-49b1-a8ad-d43238770bf8/certreq-submit-attrib-quottemplate-namequot-xxxxcsr-xxxxcer-error?forum=winserversecurity)
[How to create a certificate request with CertEnroll and .NET (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/archive/blogs/alejacma/how-to-create-a-certificate-request-with-certenroll-and-net-c)

In the first case, I understood how to form a request.

Here is an example:

---

**req.inf**

[NewRequest]

Subject = ""

KeyLength = 2048

RequestType = PKCS10

ProviderName = "Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0"

[RequestAttributes]

CertificateTemplate = ""

---

Subject - *Certificate-Details-Subject*.

CertificateTemplate - get frendly name from *Certificate-Details-Subject*, search *TemplatePropFriendlyName* in "*certutil.exe -Template*" and get  *TemplatePropCommonName*.

```
certreq -q -new req.inf req.req
certreq -config "CAHostName.domain.local\CAName" -submit "req.req" "cert.cer"
certreq -accept "cert.cer"
```

In the second case, I took example and reduced it a bit.

```
public class TestCertManager
{
    private const int CC_DEFAULTCONFIG = 0;
    private const int CC_UIPICKCONFIG = 0x1;
    private const int CR_IN_BASE64 = 0x1;
    private const int CR_IN_FORMATANY = 0;
    private const int CR_IN_PKCS10 = 0x100;
    private const int CR_DISP_ISSUED = 0x3;
    private const int CR_DISP_UNDER_SUBMISSION = 0x5;
    private const int CR_OUT_BASE64 = 0x1;
    private const int CR_OUT_CHAIN = 0x100;
    // Create request
    public string CreateRequest()
    {
        string subject = "<subject>";
        string templateName = "<templateName>";
        //  Create all the objects that will be required
        CX509CertificateRequestPkcs10 objPkcs10 = new CX509CertificateRequestPkcs10();
        CX509PrivateKey objPrivateKey = new CX509PrivateKey();
        CCspInformation objCSP = new CCspInformation();
        CCspInformations objCSPs = new CCspInformations();
        CX500DistinguishedName objDN = new CX500DistinguishedName();
        CX509Enrollment objEnroll = new CX509Enrollment();
        //  Initialize the csp object using the desired Cryptograhic Service Provider (CSP)
        objCSP.InitializeFromName("Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0");
        //  Add this CSP object to the CSP collection object
        objCSPs.Add(objCSP);
        objPrivateKey.Length = 2048;
        objPrivateKey.KeySpec = X509KeySpec.XCN_AT_SIGNATURE;
        objPrivateKey.KeyUsage = X509PrivateKeyUsageFlags.XCN_NCRYPT_ALLOW_ALL_USAGES;
        objPrivateKey.MachineContext = false;
        //  Provide the CSP collection object (in this case containing only 1 CSP object)
        //  to the private key object
        objPrivateKey.CspInformations = objCSPs;
        //  Create the actual key pair
        objPrivateKey.Create();
        //  provide a template name
    objPkcs10.InitializeFromPrivateKey(X509CertificateEnrollmentContext.ContextUser,objPrivateKey, templateName);
        //  Encode the name in using the Distinguished Name object
        objDN.Encode(
            subject,
            X500NameFlags.XCN_CERT_NAME_STR_NONE
        );
        //  Assing the subject name by using the Distinguished Name object initialized above
        objPkcs10.Subject = objDN;
        // Create enrollment request
        objEnroll.InitializeFromRequest(objPkcs10);
        string strRequest = objEnroll.CreateRequest(EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64);
        return strRequest;
    }
    // Submit request to CA and get response
    public string SendRequest(string strRequest)
    {
        //  Create all the objects that will be required
        CCertConfig objCertConfig = new CCertConfig();
        CCertRequest objCertRequest = new CCertRequest();
        string strCAConfig = @"CAHostName\CAName";
        int iDisposition;
        string strDisposition;
        string strCert;
        // Submit the request
        iDisposition = objCertRequest.Submit(CR_IN_BASE64 | CR_IN_FORMATANY, strRequest, null, strCAConfig);
        // Check the submission status
        if (CR_DISP_ISSUED != iDisposition) // Not enrolled
        {
            strDisposition = objCertRequest.GetDispositionMessage();
            if (CR_DISP_UNDER_SUBMISSION == iDisposition) // Pending
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The submission is pending: " + strDisposition);
                return "";
            }
            else // Failed
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The submission failed: " + strDisposition);
                Console.WriteLine("Last status: " + objCertRequest.GetLastStatus().ToString());
                return "";
            }

        }
        // Get the certificate
        strCert = objCertRequest.GetCertificate(CR_OUT_BASE64 | CR_OUT_CHAIN);
        return strCert;
    }
    // Install response from CA
    public void AcceptPKCS7(string strCert)
    {
        //  Create all the objects that will be required
        CX509Enrollment objEnroll = new CX509Enrollment();
        // Install the certificate
        objEnroll.Initialize(X509CertificateEnrollmentContext.ContextUser);

        objEnroll.InstallResponse(
            InstallResponseRestrictionFlags.AllowUntrustedRoot,
            strCert,
            EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64,
            null
        );
        Console.WriteLine("Certificate installed!");
    }
}
```

I'm still looking for the best solution, but at least I have 2 working options.